# Rails ActiveRecord: Find from ActiveRecord result in O(1) time

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

simple question here. Say I have an active record results like this:

@users = User.all

Later on, I want to get the data on a user with ispecific id. I could easily do `User.find('c5ab1bfc-90ac-4b59-b5d3-fd8940aab7b1')` but this will make another query to the database. I know that the user is in the list @users, so is there a way I could find a user from @users with a certain id, without making another DB query, and without looping over the @users object?

Answer (score 2):

Yep you can use #detect which will select the first match in the relation without firing off another query:

```
@user = @users.detect{ |u| u.id == 'c5ab1bfc-90ac-4b59-b5d3-fd8940aab7b1' }
```

But honestly if you are just running a simple #find query on a User (User.find params[:id]), that's not going to kill your application, unless I'm terribly mistaken.

Updated:

Thanks d34n5 for correcting me, #select will iterate through the entire collection whereas #detect (aliased #find) will stop at and return the first occurrence.

Comment: no, .select iterate through all your elements and will return every occurence that matches what's in your block. You should use the method detect or find that returns just the first occurence.

Comment: A trivialized example like this won't kill an application no, but In my real application this situation pops up several times on a page.

Comment: Yeah this is all I have ever been able to find on this, and it essentially has the same performance as a for loop with a break statement as far as I can tell.

Comment: That's what it looks like, hopefully these aren't huge collections!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can build your result in a Ruby Hash using the id as a key.

You will have a O(n) once when you will build the result, but every other access to a specific row (for example @users['c5ab1bfc-90ac-4b59-b5d3-fd8940aab7b1']) will be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

I dont suppose you mean something like?:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

or

```
@user = @users.find(params[:id])
```

Not sure if the second one would work...

Comment: Note what I said in the question, I am looking for a solution which does not   require another query or a loop through the @users database. Both of these will make a query.

Comment: Dylan, those would work just fine but OP was asking for a way to select a user that already exists in the `@users ActiveRecord::Relation` without querying the database. Find is going to fire off another query to the DB! -der